# Recursively add object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

If I have an array of arrays, each consisting of object property names (strings), how can I recursively modify an object to check whether or not the property exists and add it accordingly. The last value in the array would be applied as a string value of the given property.

```
const propsToAdd = [
    ['propA', 'value'], 
    ['propB', 'propC', 'propD', 'value'],
    ['propB', 'propF', 'value']
];
```

The resulting object would contain the relevant properties (nested accordingly) and the value of the final property would be equal to the last item in the array.

```
const resultingObj = { 
    propA: 'value', 
    propB: { 
        propC: {
            propD: 'value'
        }
        propF: 'value'
    } 
};
```

I would like to create such an object recursively, as the array will be of unknown length, as will the sub arrays.

It's important to note that the following *will not* occur and does not need be accommodated.

```
const propsToAdd = [
    ['propA', 'value'],
    ['propA', 'value', 'value1']
];
```

Put otherwise, `value` (as a child of `propA`) cannot both be a property *and* a value name.

**How can I write a recursive function that adds (and nests) key/value pairs to an object?**

Comment: is there a limit to the depth of the list of properties?

Comment: Is the value numeric here? or string "value" @Himmel

Comment: String value only.

Comment: Did you make an attempt? It would be good to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

createRec recursively creates the object in a nested form.

```js
function processInput(propsToAdd) {
  var resultingObj = {},
    propArr;

  for (var i = 0, len = propsToAdd.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    propArr = propsToAdd[i];
    createRec(propArr, resultingObj);
  }

  return resultingObj;
}

function createRec(propArr, resultingObj, index) {
  var prop,
    value_Str = 'value';
  for (var j = index || 0, len1 = propArr.length; j < len1; j += 1) {
    prop = propArr[j];
    if (!resultingObj[prop]) {
      resultingObj[prop] = {};
    }
    if (propArr[j + 1] === value_Str) {
      resultingObj[prop] = propArr[j + 1];
      j += 1;
    } else {
      createRec(propArr, resultingObj[prop], j + 1);
      j = len1;
    }
  }
}

console.log(processInput([
  ['propA', 'value'],
  ['propB', 'propC', 'propD', 'value'],
  ['propB', 'propF', 'value']
]));
```

Comment: @Himmel Please validate and let me know if you have concerns.

Answer (score 6):

Since your use of `const` suggests ES2015, you can make use of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```js
const nest = ([x, ...xs], o={}) =>
    xs.length === 0 ? x : (o[x] = nest(xs,o[x]), o);

const nestmany = ([xs, ...yss], o={}) =>
    xs === undefined ? o : nestmany(yss, nest(xs,o));

const propsToAdd = [
    ['propA', 'value1'],
    ['propB', 'propC', 'propD', 'value2'],
    ['propB', 'propF', 'value3']
];

console.log(nestmany(propsToAdd));
```

Comment: Although this works just as OP wanted it to work, coming from a slightly different angle where I need a very similar functionality as OP but with a few modifications, this answer is not great for me because I have no idea what is happening here. I would love if you could elaborate your answer with more descriptive variable names, and explaining what is happening. One liners are great until they're completely unreadable. I don't want to hate, just want to understand your code so I can use it as well. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

A closure is here to iterate over all the property lists that are to be added to the object.

Whenever a new property is found, a new object is created.
That new object is sent for further extensions.

Whenever we get to the last value of the property list, it is assigned to the current property.

```js
var addProperties = (function() {

  var addProperties = function(object, properties) {
    var currentProperty = properties.shift();
    if (properties.length === 1) {
      object[currentProperty] = properties[0];
    }
    else{
      if (!object.hasOwnProperty(currentProperty))
        object[currentProperty] = {};
      addProperties(object[currentProperty], properties);
    }
  };


  return function(object, propertiesArray) {
    propertiesArray.forEach(function(propertyList) {
      addProperties(object, propertyList);
    });
  };

}());


const propsToAdd = [
  ['propA', 'value'],
  ['propB', 'propC', 'propD', 'value'],
  ['propB', 'propF', 'value']
];
var object = {};
addProperties(object, propsToAdd);
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recursive version, but why not?

```
function createObj( propsToAdd ){
    obj = {}
    for( var i = 0; i < propsToAdd.length; i++ ){
       var tmp = obj;
       var props = propsToAdd[i];
       for( var j = 0; j < props.length-2; j++ ){
           var prop_name = props[ j ];
           if( !( prop_name in tmp ) ) 
               tmp[ prop_name ] = {}
           tmp = tmp[ prop_name ];
       }
       if( props.length > 1 )
          tmp[ props[ j ] ] = props[ j + 1 ]
       else 
          obj = props[0];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
const resultingObj={propA:'value6'};
const propsToAdd=[
    [
        'propA',
        'value1'
    ],
    [
        'propB',
        'propC',
        'propD',
        'value2'
    ],
    [
        'propB',
        'propF',
        'value3'
    ]
];
function addObjectProperties(properties)
    {
        properties.forEach(property=>
        {
            property.reduce(function(previous,current,idx,arr)
            {
                return idx===arr.length-1
                   ? previous
                   : idx===arr.length-2
                     ? previous[current]=arr[arr.length-1]
                     : previous[current]??={};
            },resultingObj);
        });
    };
```

Usage;

```
addObjectProperties(propsToAdd);
```

Result;

```
resultingObj=
    {
        propA:'value1',
        propB:{
            propC:{
                propD: 'value2'
            },
            propF: 'value3'
        }
    };
```

From the question:

> It's important to note that the following will not occur and does not
> need be accommodated.

In a scenario where paths and values come separated, please use the following function instead;

```
function addObjectProperties(properties,value={})
    {
        properties.forEach(property=>
        {
            property.reduce(function(previous,current,idx,arr)
            {
                return previous[current]??=idx===arr.length-1
                                       ? value
                                       : {};
            },resultingObj);
        });
    };
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)